# Umbraco media section missing?

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco5

I'm admin, but I can't see the media node anymore, I can't see it in my user section, where I can give users access to sections?

ANyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this, this can be caused by, the startMediaID in the DB being incorrectly set to -1 (somehow) change it to a node value.